# get graph data from large table using nth_value window function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to plot a graph of the data from a large table. I can get all of it easily by doing basically

```
select id, value from data order by value desc;
```

but that yields me about a hundred thousand rows. About 50 are enough for my purpose, so I want to basically have the equivalent of a **step** function. Searching turned up "nth_value" as the appropriate window function that probably does what I need, but I couldn't find examples on how to actually use it for this purpose.

Or maybe there's a better way even?

(I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 in case it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very wary of using `row_number()` without an `order by` clause.

One way to phrase this is:

```
select id, value 
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as n,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from data d
     ) d 
 where n % floor(cnt / 50) = 0;
```

This will typically return either 50 or 51 rows.  If you want exactly 50 rows, you can add `fetch first 50 rows`.

Comment: accepted this answer over the other one because it answers exactly the question that I had asked.

Answer (score 1):

You want only the first 50 rows?

```
select id, value 
  from data 
 order by value desc 
 limit 50;
```

Every 50th row?

```
select id, value 
  from (select id, value, row_number() over () as n 
          from data) d 
 where n % 50 = 0
```

You can choose whatever ordering you want in the `OVER` clause, e.g. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC)`

Every nth row to get 50 results?

```
select id, value 
  from (select id, value, row_number() over () as n 
          from data) d 
 where n % ((select count(*) from d) / 50) = 0
```

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c88fdf6c60595ca25e5747693eb79835)

Comment: the 3rd is actually what I want, but ordered by value. thanks!

Comment: just add the `ORDER BY value` in the `OVER` clause et voilà!

Comment: if possible, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer so that future users know it's correct and helpful.

Comment: upvoted, per the custom I'll wait for other answers before accepting.